# tsql query efficiency

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ListingStats](
    [ListingStatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StatTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ListingID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ListingStats] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ListingStatID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am trying to get 4 totals for each type (listingStatTypeID) for today, last 7 days, last 30 days, and all time.

I am not really sure what the most efficient query will be.  Right now I have the following that I can repeat for each TYPE but that will be a big query and it will be a lot of calls.

```
declare @listingID int
set @listingID = 209722
--today
select count(1) from ListingStats where listingid = @listingid and CreatedDate = getdate()
--last 7 days
select count(1) from ListingStats where listingid = @listingid and CreatedDate > getdate()-7
--last 30 days
select count(1) from ListingStats where listingid = @listingid and CreatedDate > getdate()-30 
--all time
select count(1) from ListingStats where listingid = @listingid
```

I am always calling this for one listing at a time by providing a listingID.
If anyone could provide a direction I would appreciate it. Should I create a view of some sort?

**Expected Results**

```
-Type------Today-----7Days---30Days---Ever
  1         44        50       500    5000
  2         22        40       90     1000
  3         55        55       555    5555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single listing, you can use CASE expressions to get the four values in a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate = getdate()    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_month,
       COUNT(*) AS v_alltime
  FROM ListingStats
 WHERE listingid = @listingid
```

For all listing IDs, then

```
SELECT ListingID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate = getdate()    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_month,
       COUNT(*) AS v_alltime
  FROM ListingStats
 GROUP BY ListingID
```

If you want to get summaries for each StatTypeID (within a ListingID), then:

```
SELECT ListingID,
       StatTypeID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate = getdate()    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_month,
       COUNT(*) AS v_alltime
  FROM ListingStats
 GROUP BY ListingID, StatTypeID
```

If you want the summaries by StatTypeID across all ListingIDs, then:

```
SELECT StatTypeID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate = getdate()    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_month,
       COUNT(*) AS v_alltime
  FROM ListingStats
 GROUP BY StatTypeID
```

Judging from the 'expected results' section that has been added, this last query is closest to what you need.  And judging from the comments, if you want the summaries by StatTypeID for a specific ListingID, then:

```
SELECT StatTypeID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate = getdate()    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > getdate()-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v_month,
       COUNT(*) AS v_alltime
  FROM ListingStats
 WHERE ListingID = @listingid
 GROUP BY StatTypeID
```

If there are issues with your `getdate()` function calls (as suggested by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27488159/15168)), you also need to fix those.

Comment: I think your last query is what I am looking for, but changing the end to   where listingid = @listingid
 GROUP BY  StatTypeID and removing listingid from select, also fixing the date as Gordon pointed out

Comment: Is there any benefit in putting this query in a view? it will be called on demand (user has to click a button to bring the stats up)

Comment: If you're still looking for the information for a single ListingID value, then yes, modify the last query with `WHERE ListingID = @listingid`.

Comment: The benefit of the view is that you write `SELECT * FROM ViewName WHERE ListingID = @listingid` instead of the long query.  If there are going to be multiple places where you need the information, then a view centralizes the query.  So yes, there could be some benefit to creating a view.

Comment: perfect thanks, also is there an easy way to add a fifth column that will be the sum of all the other sums instead of looping and adding them together?

Comment: Does it make sense to quadruple count today's changes, triple count the changes in the last week that were not made today, double count the changes made in the last month that were not made in the last week, and single count the rest?  If I were doing it, I'd probably run the query as a sub-query, and then calculate the results: `SELECT StatTypeID, v_today, v_week, v_month, v_alltime, v_today + v_week + w_month + v_alltime FROM (SELECT ...last query...) AS main_query`.  (According to the SQL Standard, the `AS main_query` is needed; you might be able to omit it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  This puts the values into four columns:

```
select sum(case when CreatedDate = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when CreatedDate > cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as lastweek,
       sum(case when CreatedDate > cast(getdate() - 30 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as last30,
       count(*) as ever  
from ListingStats
where listingid = @listingid;
```

Note that `getdate()` returns a `datetime`, with a time component (despite the name), so this query casts the value to a date (removing the time component).

To get this for all listing ids:

```
select sum(case when CreatedDate = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when CreatedDate > cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as lastweek,
       sum(case when CreatedDate > cast(getdate() - 30 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as last30,
       count(*) as ever  
from ListingStats
group by listingid;
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have to do this for reach type, should i be calling the same query for each type or is there more efficient way to separate them, I will update original post on how i need the result to look like

Comment: adding that column in `group by <columns>` will do your work.